# Mistake in javascript with NaN in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan

When I execute this function in javascript, I get a NaN result. It seems quite ilogical beacuse the arrays employed in this operation are all numerical and are shown properly when I do so with a Alert(); I left the code here for your supervision:

```
function calculation_errors(){      
    arr_error_P_t2=new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<arr_P_t1.length;i++){
        var K=new Number(arr_K_t1[i]);
        var P=new Number(arr_P_t1[i]);      
        arr_error_P_t2[i]=(Math.sqrt(1+Math.pow(m_t2,2)))*(Math.sqrt((Math.pow(1/K,2)+(Math.pow(1/P,2)))));
    }
    alert(arr_error_P_t2.join('\n'));
}
```

Comment: "The Number() function converts the object argument to a number that represents the object's value.

If the value cannot be converted to a legal number, NaN is returned."

Comment: This code is incomplete in the sense that it references things we can't see.  Could you construct a self-contained example in http://jsfiddle.net that malfunctions in a similar way and post the link?

Comment: @Paul he is definitely accessing a array element that doesn't exist. See my answer below. Doing a fiddle is a good thing but I think that should solve the problem. :)

Comment: From comments (PRPGFerret) it looks like he found an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting a `NaN` is because your array `arr_K_t1` has a length that is smaller than your array `arr_P_t1`.

In your `for loop` :
You are trying to get an array element that is greater its own size with the statement

`var K= arr_K_t1[i];`

it returns `undefined` (because you have exceeded the number of elements in `arr_K_t1`. So in javascript it returns `undefined` if you try to access a non-existent element of an array.

Then you are doing mathematical operations on it which obviously return `NaN` (the result that you have got).

The solution is this :

```
function calculation_errors(){      
    arr_error_P_t2=new Array();

    //COMMENT : You are assuming array "arr_K_t1" is atleast of length equal to 
    //array "arr_P_t1" in the for loop that follows 
    //THIS IS A WRONG ASSUMPTION AND IS LEADING TO THE "NaN" at the end !!
    ...
    ...
    ...rest of your code
```

**Edit** : I haven't been able to include the remaining code because its making the post weird. However the problem lies in the `for loop` where he is accessing an element that does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Instead using `new Number()`, just multiply your value with 1 `(your_val * 1)`. Its the easiest and fastest way to convert a value into integer.

```
function calculation_errors() {
    arr_error_P_t2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr_P_t1.length; i++) {
        var K = arr_K_t1[i] * 1;
        var P = arr_P_t1[i] * 1;
        arr_error_P_t2[i] = (Math.sqrt(1 + Math.pow(m_t2, 2))) * (Math.sqrt((Math.pow(1 / K, 2) + (Math.pow(1 / P, 2)))));
    }
    alert(arr_error_P_t2.join('\n'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert the numbers into objects, and that should solve your NaN issue.

```
function calculation_errors(){      
    arr_error_P_t2=new Array();

    for(var i=0;i<arr_P_t1.length;i++){
        var K= arr_K_t1[i];
        var P= arr_P_t1[i];      
        arr_error_P_t2.push((Math.sqrt(1+Math.pow(m_t2,2)))*(Math.sqrt((Math.pow(1/K,2)+(Math.pow(1/P,2)))))); 
        //I prefer .push() but you don't have to use this part
    }

    alert(arr_error_P_t2.join('\n'));
}
```

Comment: Hum....Unfortunately, anything there does work. I've found that erasing "m_t2" makes possible to see the resulting array, so I think the issue has a lot to do on how that variable is created.

Comment: @ViceNocillator check my solution above .. that should help you solve the problem. Hope that helps :) . Boy did this one take a lot of time . Let me know if it helped you solve it :)

Comment: I KNOW WHAT WAS HAPPENING! The m_t2 variable was empty. It was used in other function that I should have called before in the html.

Comment: But I'll improve the code adding the solution provided by PRPGFerret. Thanks a lot for all your answers, guys!

Answer (score 0):

You must be insert at least one item inside that array.

`var arr_error_P_t2=[1]`

Comment: Would help better to indicate to which array you're referring in your answer

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have to use `"new Number()"`? It would be an object if you do that.
Objects cannot be printed directly.

Comment: Humm.. I thought it was a way to be sure that I would be managing numbers. Someone told me that javascript could be quite a bit tricky in than sense...